How to find residual data from disk spill in spark application?
I have a spark application which on querying may have a disk spill of intermediate data. How to find which how  much of this spilled data is residual data(which is not being used or will not be used anymore)?
I want to stop this process if at any point in time(at any task) the residual data becomes huge(assume some threshold).
So far I see there is an accumulator diskBytesSpilled which gives the amount of bytes written to local disk, but I don't know how much of this is residual.
